# LINQ - Entity framework code first - Grouped results to custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a web application using Entity Framework code first and I want to be able to hook up my example data below into various Entity data aware controls in ASP.NET.

By using the ItemType property of the control to specify my custom cencapsulation class and the SelectMethod property of the control to call the LINQ queryI need to return an IQueryable collection which the control can use and work with automatic pagination etc.

Lets assume we have an entity to start with :-

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int MyObjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

So this LINQ query will work fine

```
public IQueryable<MyObject> GetMyObjects()
{
    SiteContext db = new SiteContext();

     var myObjects = (from m in db.MyObjects
                        select m);

    return myObjects;
}
```

Now using the following sample data :-

```
MyObjectId  Name
1   Apple
2   Orange
3   Apple
4   Apple
5   Pear
6   Orange
7   Apple
8   Grapes
9   Apple
10  Orange
```

What I want to do is group the data and provide a count like this:-

```
Name    Count
Apple   5
Orange  3
Pear    1
Grapes  1
```

So my first step is to create a class to encapsulate the Entity and provide the additional count column :-

```
public class MyObjectWithCount
{
    public MyObject MyObject { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get some results with a LINQ query

```
public IQueryable<MyObjectWithCount> GetMyObjectsWithCount()
{
    SiteContext db = new SiteContext();

     var myObjects = (from m in db.MyObjects
                      group m by m.Name into grouped
                      select new MyObjectWithCount()
                      {
                          MyObject = grouped,
                          Count = ?what goes here?
                      });

    return myObjects;
}
```

So I have 2 problems with my select new MyObjectWithCount()

**1) How do I get the count for each grouped item**

**2) How do I convert grouped into Myobject. As it stands, I get the design time error of cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.grouping to MyObject.**

If I did not perform grouping in the LINQ query, then I am able to successfully return an IQueryable to my control and it all hooks up fine (but obviously the count is missing at this stage)

Also to clarify, this is an oversimplied example of my Entity/class, I do need to have access to the full MyObject entity as in the real world there will be many fields, and not just a name field as in the example above.

Thanks everyone for any help you can offer

Comment: You have some apples with different MyObjectId. What MyObjectId do you want to be in MyObjectWithCount.MyObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this linq query:

```
var myObjects = (from m in db.MyObjects
                      group m by m.Name into grouped
                      select new MyObjectWithCount()
                      {
                          MyObject = grouped.FirstOrDefault(),
                          Count = grouped.Count()
                      });
```

In this case your MyObjectProperty will have MyObjectId and other properties of first element in group.

If you have same other then MyObjectId properties for all objects with same Name, you should group by all properties excluding MyObjectId:

```
var myObjects = (from m in db.MyObjects
                          group m by new {m.Name, m.AnyOtherProperty, ...} into grouped
                          select new MyObjectWithCount()
                          {
                              MyObject = grouped.FirstOrDefault(),
                              Count = grouped.Count()
                          });
```

It will protect you from collapsing of group of different objects in one object.

Comment: Thankyou, this solution corrected my grouping / counting issue as requested

Answer (score 0):

Your `Select` is slightly off.

Also, as your return type is `IQueryable<MyObjectWithCount>` add `AsQueryable`.

**EDIT: From your comments, you want to return the items in your class too, in that case you'd have to do the following:**

Add another property to `MyObjectWithCount` to hold the matching properties and a string to contain the Name searched on:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<MyObject> MatchingObjects { get; set; }
```

Then your `Count` can just work off that:

```
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        return MatchingObjects.Count;
    }
}
```

Then your LINQ will be:

```
var myObjects = (from m in db.MyObjects
                  group m by m.Name into grouped
                  select new MyObjectWithCount
                  {
                      Name = grouped.Key,
                      MatchingObjects = grouped.ToList()
                  }).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thankyou for the quick and helpful response. You have immediately helped me with 2 points there ( grouped.Count() and AsQueryable() ) However the solution is not yet complete. I  might need to add to my question to make it more obvious, but with your solution above, grouped.Key gives me a cannot convert String to MyObject error as grouped.Key appears to be just the MyObject.Name field and not the entire MyObject

Comment: @user2437066 No problems. As for the key, that's how grouping works. You'd have to return the Name as the Key (as that's what was grouped on)

Comment: My encapsulation class MyObjectwithCount, must contain both the entire MyObject entity and the additional Count field, is there an alternative way the achieve this correctly without using grouped by. So an alternative way of asking the question is, how can I can get a list of the unique "Name" values from the "MyObject" entity, along with a count of the number of times each "Name" occurs. I will also require all fields in the MyObject to be returned. We are so close with your LINQ above.

Comment: @user2437066 Check my edit, as multiple `MyObject`s match a name, you'll need to restructure your `MyObjectWithCount` class and change the LINQ slightly.

Comment: Thankyou for all of your help mattytommo, you provided a partially working solution with helped lead to the accepted solution, unfortunately I think my intention was not 100% clear